# Internal error whan I want insert colum in Odoo

Tags: python, database, security, odoo

I don't know why but I have a problem with ir.model.access.csv when I want insert a new fields in database.

When I restart Odoo, I have this error 
Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.

My ir.model.access.csv

```
id,name,model_id:id,group_id:id,perm_read,perm_write,perm_create,perm_unlink
res_partner.access_res_partner_clicshopping,res.partner clicshopping,account.model_res_partner,base.group_sale_manager,1,1,1,1
```

my res_partner.py

```
from openerp.osv import fields, osv
from openerp.tools.translate import _

class res_partner(osv.osv):
    _inherit = 'res.partner'
    _description = "ClicShopping partner"

   _columns = {  
            'clicshopping_note_customers': fields.text('Note on Customers', translate=True, help="Specific Information"),
   }
```

_init.py

```
from . import models
```

**openerp**.py

```
# any module necessary for this one to work correctly
    'depends': [
                'account',
                'account_accountant',
                'account_voucher',
                'sale',
                'product',
                'stock'
        ],


    'external_dependencies': {
        'python': [],
    },

    # always loaded
    'data': [
             'security/ir.model.access.csv',
             'views/product_clicshopping_view.xml',
             'views/res_partner.xml',
        ],
```

res_partner.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<openerp>
    <data>
        <record model="ir.ui.view" id="res_partner_form">
        <field name="name">res.partner_clicshopping_partner</field>
        <field name="model">res.partner</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="base.view_partner_form"/> <!-- external_id -->
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <notebook position="inside">
                <page string="ClicShopping">
                </page>
            </notebook>
        </field>
        </record>
    </data> 
</openerp>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code it looks like you want to declare a 'Text' field for entering some kind of notes, but your declaration is wrong, try the following:

`'clicshopping_note_customers': fields.text("Notes on Customers")`

Try it out.

Comment: can you post your full code and are you sure due to adding of this field, you are facing the error? Did you checked the log, is it pointing to any specific area of error?

Comment: still i can see that you have not changed the declaration did you tried fields.text, because text.integer is definitely wrong.

Comment: it work,the pb come from  indentation level !! Thank